# How to change different org-roam-capture-dailies-template by working days or weekend?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I have a template, and it works fine. Now I just wonder if there is a way to use A template in working days and use B template in weekend.

```
  (setq org-roam-dailies-capture-templates
        `(("d" "default" entry "* %<%H:%M:%S>  \n   %? \n\n"
        :if-new (file+head "%<%Y-%m-%d>.org"
                      ,(concat "#+title: %<%Y-%m-%d>\n"
                        "\n"
                        "%<%Y-%m-%d %A %W weeks %j days>\n"
                        "\n"
                        "*Don't ignore your dreams; don't work too much; say what you think; cultivate friendships; be happy*\n"
                        "\n"
                        ))
         :unnarrowed t)))
```